# Place an "X" beside every value that also appears in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a Google sheet to consolidate information from different departments.

I have a list of product numbers in column A.  I want to compare those values with another column of values on another sheet.

If the value in column A exists in the other column, I want the formula to return an "X".

I have come up with this so far but it is only working for one value in my test list. Please help.

```
=IF($A:$A=E:E, "X", "")
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171617/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `match()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula(if(ifna(match(A1:A, Sheet2!E1:E, 0)), "X", iferror(ø)))
```

Put the formula in row 1 of a free column. See [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).